# Java BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Unknown access type record

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

i'm following a tutorial online on spring boot but i'm running into this error and i don't know what to do to solve it.
My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Popster_Backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my Entity class:

```java
package com.example.demo.user;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class user {

        @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
        private String name;
        private String birthday;
        private String email;
        private String Nickname;
        private String password;

    public user() {
    }

    public user(String name, String birthday, String email, String nickname, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        Nickname = nickname;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public user(String birthday, String email, String nickname, String password) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        Nickname = nickname;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return Nickname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        Nickname = nickname;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "user{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", birthday='" + birthday + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", Nickname='" + Nickname + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

userConfig

```java
package com.example.demo.user;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class userConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(userRepository userRepo){
        return args -> {
            user NameUser = new user("Name", "date", "email", "nick", "password");
            user NameUserTwo = new user("Name", "date", "email","Nick","password");
            userRepo.saveAll(List.of(NameUser, NameUserTwo));
        };

    }
}
```

userRepository

```
package com.example.demo.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<user, String> {

}
```

userService

```
package com.example.demo.user;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class userService {

    private final userRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public userService(userRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }


    public List<user> getUser(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

userController

```
package com.example.demo.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path= "api/v1/user")
public class userController {

    private final userService serv;

    @Autowired
    public userController(userService service){
        this.serv = service;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<user> getUser(){
        return serv.getUser();
    }
}
```

The error i get:

```
*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unknown access type record
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.example.demo.PopsterBackendApplication.main(PopsterBackendApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown access type record
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:131) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:121) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyContainer.<init>(PropertyContainer.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.InheritanceState.postProcess(InheritanceState.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:417) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 16 common frames omitted*
```

Can anybody help me? I'm not new to Spring but i have to re-learn it from zero due to a huge memory loss after i got run over by a car and that's what i'm doing.
Thanks in advance. If you need further details just ask.

Comment: Sounds like a library version mismatch between your build and deployment environments.  Make sure your build environment matches exactly the deployment environment.

Comment: Remove the `org.hibernate` dependencies they aren't compatible. Fix the `javax.persistence` imports to `jakarta.persistence` and restart the application.

Comment: In addition, depending on which database you use `user` is a reserved keyword which can lead to issues as well.

Comment: How can i check the version mismatch

Answer (score -1):

Your user entity is missing `this` keyword when setting value of nickname, try these

Change

```
private String Nickname;
```

To

```
private String nickname;
```

Change

```
public user(String name, String birthday, String email, String nickname, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.email = email;
    Nickname = nickname;
    this.password = password;
}
```

To

```
public user(String name, String birthday, String email, String nickname, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.email = email;
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Change

```
public String getNickname() {
    return Nickname;
}
```

To

```
public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}
```

Change

```
public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    Nickname = nickname;
}
```

To

```
public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}
```

Comment: As long as the fields have different names adding `this` won't change a thing (nor is it the cause for this error).

Comment: Actually getter setters and contructor were generated by Intellij but i'll change them if it's the case, i also get warnings of vulnerable dependencies on my pom, maybe could be that?